# Java 'Email Sending Code' > Known Exception (Index: 14, Size: 14)?

Tags: java, email, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

i have an automation framework which will send an email when there are test failures, most of the time the code will work however i seem to be getting a strange exception occurring when the following Exception is triggered in turn not sending any emails due to the exception listed:

```
public class SendEmailFile {
    public static void sendEmailReport(String detailsEmailTitle, String detailsEmailBody) {
        {
            // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
            String to = "user123@mail.com";
            // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
            String from = "user123@mail.com";

            // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
            String host = "cluxxxx.eu.messagelabs.com";
            // Get system properties
            Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            // Setup mail server
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
            // Get the default Session object.
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            try {
                // Create a default MimeMessage object.
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

                // Set From: header field of the header.
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

                // Set To: header field of the header.
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

                //CC code works:
                message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse("user321@buyagift.co.uk"));

                // Set Subject: header field
                message.setSubject(detailsEmailTitle);

                // Create the message part
                BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();


                // Create a multipar message
                Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

                // Set text message part
                messageBodyPart.setContent(EmailTemplate.setupTemplate(), "text/html");
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                //messageBodyPart.setContent("<h1>This is actual message embedded in HTML tags</h1>" + "<h2>example text</h2>", "text/html");

                /**Report Sending Functionality 
                messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
                String filename ="C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Desktop\\xxxxx\\xxxx\\target\\surefire-reports\\emailable-report.html";
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                ***/

                // Send the complete message parts
                message.setContent(multipart);

                // Send message
                Transport.send(message);
                System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

            } catch (MessagingException mex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to Send Email!, Exception: " + mex.getMessage());
                mex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception which is captured within the Jenkins build when attempting to send an email:

```
TEST CLASS END TIME: 05.22.45
Unable to send email which contains test details, Exception: Index: 14, Size: 14
Tests run: 307, Failures: 81, Errors: 0, Skipped: 204, Time elapsed: 41.355 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
clickOn_PaySecurelyNowButton(BuyFramework.complete.AddingDrivingExperienceToBasketTest)  Time elapsed: 0.246 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BuyFramework.complete.AddingDrivingExperienceToBasketTest.clickOn_PaySecurelyNowButton(AddingDrivingExperienceToBasketTest.java:51)

EmailFormatAndDataCapture(BuyFramework.complete.AddingDrivingExperienceToBasketTest)  Time elapsed: 0.252 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: 
unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Click OK to confirm your personal message is correct as this is exactly how it will be printed.}
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2 milliseconds: null
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'BG146', ip: '172.16.2.162', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\Gxxxx~1.BRU\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir11396_18538}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: a9648e2aa647ebcbc6b69366b783b50c
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the sendEmailReport method is being called? The error message 'Unable to send email which contains test details' is not the one in the method you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be your clue:

> org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException:  unexpected alert open:
>   {Alert text : Click OK to confirm your personal message is correct as
>   this is exactly how it will be printed.}

It looks like your code does not expect, and therefore not handle a pop-up alert?

Ideally you should add a general exception catch line to your try/catch.

Comment: ok thanks @Bill Hileman ill try to catch the alert Exception and then call the method again